# Is it possible to change the font of Adobe Flash Player in Google Chrome?

Tags: 12.04, flash, fonts, adobe

I suppose this might be an odd question, but the Ubuntu font looks horrible in some Adobe Flash Player applications in Google Chrome and therefore I was wondering if it was possible to change this font. I'm not quite sure what font is being used, I just thought it was Ubuntu's.

I'm used to Windows font for Adobe Flash Player applications, which looks better than the font currently being used.

I presume it's using the same font my whole system is using? If so; how do I change that?

Best Regards,
Hexicidal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could it be that you're missing some standard fonts, and the closest match isn't close enough?

Just guessing here, but from what i remember flash handles fonts in 2 ways, embedding them (should look just the same on every system) and using defaults from the system (kind of like in html, where you can specify "Arial, Verdana, .." and it will attempt to use these in order if available.)

Do you have the corefonts installed? If not try installing them with

```
sudo apt-get install ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

and see if that fixes it.